# Switching to ShouldAlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread(false) MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

We are in the process of moving from MVVMCross 4.1 to 4.4. One of the main things for us to consider is the MvxTaskBasedBindingContext  that was introduced in 4.2.

In the [MVVMCross 4.2 docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-4.2/) it says

> To take full advantage of the MvxTaskBasedBindingContext, you should
>   also call ShouldAlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread(false); in the
>   ViewModel constructor.

MvxTaskBasedBindingContext sounds like a good thing and therefore we want to take "full advantage" of it. However unsurprisingly, no longer always raising  INotifyPropertyChanged on the UI Thread gives us plenty of Thread Marshalling errors

"*Application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread*"

Is there a suggested approach to moving to the ShouldAlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread(false) model and is only worth it in certain scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3b70cbeffdc8d00531fc06002ea2fca651308d45/MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.cs#L130) of `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged`, you'll see that `RaisePropertyChanged` by default marshals `PropertyChanged` events to the UI thread.

So if you are performing Unit Tests on the PropertyChanged event they'll probably break because there is no `Dispatcher`. Setting `ShouldAlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread(false)` will prevent this situation and the raise will be done directly on the thread you are in that moment.

This is also handy when you are subscribed to `PropertyChanged` in another thread on purpose.

If you want you can set it to `false` and make a method on your base viewmodel class to do:

`this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName));`

So you always use your `RaisePropertyChangedOnMainThread` (let's name it like this) and no thread marshalling errors occur.

Source: http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20140324-HandlingPropertyChangedEventInMvvmCrossViewModelUnitTests.html

HIH